# Llamada a modal no me funciona con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, modal

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, la cosa al momento de enviarle los datos por metodo ajax con el siguente codigo

```
function Cargar(){
            var Url="aqui va a la segunda pagina";
            var id_Ticket_modal = document.getElementById("id").value; // obtengo la variable que deseo
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: Url,
                dataType: 'text',
                data:{id_Ticket_modal} // Le envio los datos por metodo POST
            }).done(function(datos){
              console.log(datos);
              $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal
            }).fail(function(){
              alert("Error al buscar datos");
            });
        }
```

El botón es simple solo lo estoy llamando con onclick y bueno en la consola me trae los datos de la segunda página obteniendo el post de la variable que le mando por ajax.

El problema está, en que cuando carga el "done", no me trae ningún modal y por si tienen dudas ese modal también está en la segunda página.

Es básicamente enviarle datos al modal tipo post a un "Actions" y que habrá el modal que esta adentro.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a mi propia pregunta primero tienes que declarar un div dentro de la primera página    `<div id="exampleModal"></div>` porque no existe antes de llamarlo y la lamada en el done esta es la correcta

```
.done(function(datos){
              console.log(datos);
              $('div.modal').html(datos); 
              $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle'); //Llamada al segundo modal               
            })
```